# I was asked to submit the offer letter from a previous company. What should I do?

Tags: hiring-process, india

I was asked to share my previous company's offer letter to the HR department, during a job interview. Should I reconsider joining this company?

Comment: Hello there welcome to the Workplace. Please [edit] your post and clarify on the following: your location and context? in what way or tone did they ask you this? why you you feel it's something that would make you reconsider joining them?

Comment: Why would you reconsider joining? You have the letter so show it. Unless the letter does not match what you told them - then I can see why you may no longer wish to join...

Comment: @DarkCygnus Thanks for your advice, I feel not to disclose the location because I work at a IT industry and most of the time we work for remote clients. i am aware of Hr asking for relieving letter from previous company but not the offer letter which contains more personal informations as well the Initial CTC which later they may keep as margin to bargain the salary rather current market value. reconsidering since I have more offers with better policies.

Comment: Communications between you and your previous employer are private and confidential, there is no reason a prospective employer needs to see any of them. Just Tell them it’s confidential.

Comment: "i am aware of Hr asking for reliving letter" So, you are asking about India?

Comment: @Matt thanks for the advice, truly appreciate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HR Forcing to submit documents prior to give offer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/158665/hr-forcing-to-submit-documents-prior-to-give-offer)

Comment: Or this one? [How to hide my previous salary during salary negotiation?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/64118/35882)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Claim you can't find it or that the company said it was confidential.**

They are trying to lock your salary expectation down to a certain level and they want to know what you were paid there so they can set the salary range right from the start. Sharing it is very unlikely to benefit you.

Comment: exactly the same thought i am having.

Comment: Note though that it is usual practice in India to ask for proof of previous employment either in the form of offer letter, salary slip or relieving letter. So the diplomatic approach would be to give them the relieving letter from the previous employer, while making sure that you don't share salary and other personal or confidential information.